# How do I convert a variable from string to sympy.core.add.Add explicitly in python?

Tags: python, string, sympy

I have a variable which is of type
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
I need to perform split so I converted it to a string using str()
Now, I have to perform certain operations for which I need it to be of <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>

How do I convert a variable from string to sympy.core.add.Add explicitly in python?

Comment: The quick&dirty would be the sympy.S function, I guess. But it sounds weird. I'm sure there is a more clean way to do what you want. Why do you need a str in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone came here later with same problem. I found this **sympify** function and it works for me. It can be used to convert string function received in the input into the sympy.core.add.Add type.

Link to the docs
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html

Comment: how can you do the opposite, from simply.core.add.Add to string?

Comment: unfortunately depends on how big is the variable I guess because in my case the computer get stuck and does not show any result